# attach authorizer to api gateway V2 route in aws cloudformation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

How to attach authorizer to api gateway V2 route in aws cloudformation?

I am using Api Gateway v2 and cloudformation.

I am using stages "prod" and "stg" I would like to work on separate lambda stg and prod.

In AWS console it is just one click of one button "Attach Authorization" in "Routes" section

I am using simple authorizer:

My cloudformation looks like this:

```
  Authorizer:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Authorizer'
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      AuthorizerPayloadFormatVersion: 2.0
      AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 5
      AuthorizerType: REQUEST
      AuthorizerUri: !Join 
        - ''
        - - 'arn:'
          - !Ref 'AWS::Partition'
          - ':apigateway:'
          - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
          - 'arn:aws:lambda:'
          - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          - ':'
          - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
          - :function:${stageVariables.AuthorizerFunctionName}
          - /invocations
      EnableSimpleResponses: true
      IdentitySource:
        - '$request.header.Authorization'
      Name: !Sub ${ProjectName}-gateway-authorizer

  MyRoute:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      AuthorizationType: CUSTOM
      AuthorizerId: !Ref Authorizer
      RouteKey: 'POST /posts/all'
      Target: !Join
        - /
        - - integrations
          - !Ref PostsLambdaIntegrationGet
```

Authorizer lambda body:

```
import json
# import jwt

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('*********** The event is: ***************')
    print(event)
    
    print('headers is:')
    print(event['headers'])
    
    print('headers Authorization is:')
    # !!!!! DONWCASE by postam or api !!!!! "A" -> "a"
    print(event['headers']['authorization'])
    
    
    if event['headers']['authorization'] == 'abc123':
        response = {
            "isAuthorized": True,
            "context": {
                "anyotherparam": "values"
            }
        }
    else:
        response = {
            "isAuthorized": False,
            "context": {
                "anyotherparam": "values"
            }
        }
    
    print('response is:')
    print(response)
    
    return response
```

BTW I do not see this option in cli [apigatewayv2 cli documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/index.html) too:

Comment: Do you have an Authorizer created? Or do you know what type of authorizers you need/want?

Comment: Yes, I have authorizer and after "attach authorization" in console it works perfect, I checked it in postman. I need it in cloudformation.

Comment: No problem; I think I have all the info needed to have something for you.

Comment: sorry I couldn't help. Today has not been good for my solutions.

Comment: the only way I found so far is update via aws cli:
```aws apigatewayv2 update-route --api-id 84(...)bke --authorization-type CUSTOM --route-id we(...)c6 --authorizer-id om(...)mf```